# Glassfish - bin/asadmin create-network-listener is failing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glassfish

I have a very strange problem that doesn't seem to exist anywhere on the internet... I am following a guide to install an application and I need to "Create a new HTTP listeners for AJP connections". I need to use the command line instead of going into the admin console so this can be automated...

here is the command I tried to run:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-1404:/home/glassfish$ sudo /home/glassfish/bin/asadmin create-network-listener –-address 127.0.0.1 --protocol http-listener-1 --listenerport 8009 --jkenabled true http-listener-ajp1
```

It then asked for the following input

```
Enter the value for the listenerport option> 8009
Enter the value for the protocol option>  http-listener-1
```

then printed the following error:

```
Command create-network-listener only accepts one operand
Usage: asadmin [asadmin-utility-options] create-network-listener
        [--address <address>] --listenerport <listenerport>
        [--threadpool <threadpool(default:http-thread-pool)>]
        --protocol <protocol> [--transport <transport(default:tcp)>]
        [--enabled[=<enabled(default:true)>]]
        [--jkenabled[=<jkenabled(default:false)>]]
        [--target <target(default:server)>] [-?|--help[=<help(default:false)>]]
        name
Command create-network-listener failed.
```

So I tried again, with the following command (not specifying any options):

```
vagrant@ubuntu-1404:/home/glassfish$ sudo /home/glassfish/bin/asadmin create-network-listener http-listener-ajp1
Enter the value for the listenerport option> 8009
Enter the value for the protocol option>  http-listener-1
```

and got this error:

```
remote failure: The specified protocol  http-listener-1 is not yet configured
Command create-network-listener failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out there is something messed up with the text I copied in from the guide.. the dashes aren't the normal dashes, they are the special character '–' (which looks identical to the normal minus sign in the terminal!) and it's interpreting the options as regular text so it looks like each option is really an operator.